# ERROR IMPORT DATABASE MYSQL MAGENTO 2.4

Tags: magento2.4.2

I'm getting an error after importing mysql database

I exported the database from the old database with the same settings as the new one

Server version 8.0.23

Has anyone come across this error, or do you know how to solve it?

Thank you in advance! Hugs

Comment: can you please share the error

Answer (score 0):

try this command for export database and import it

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -u db_user -p db_name | sed -e 's/DEFINER=[^*]*\*/\*/' > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3995 Character set 'utf8_general_ci' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like., query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `tdv`.`value` AS `default_value`, `tsv`.`value` AS `store_default_value`, IF(tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.value, tdv.value) AS `value`, IF(br.store_id = 1, br.brand_id, NULL) AS `brand_id`, `br`.`brand_id`, 1 AS `store_id`, `br`.`page_title`, `br`.`url_key`, `br`.`short_description`, `br`.`description`, `br`.`is_featured`, `br`.`static_block`, `br`.`meta_title`, `br`.`meta_keywords`, `br`.`meta_description`, `br`.`image`, `sw`.`type` AS `swatch_type`, `sw`.`value` AS `swatch_value` FROM `eav_attribute_option` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `tdv` ON tdv.option_id = main_table.option_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `tsv` ON tsv.option_id = main_table.option_id AND tsv.store_id = '1'
 LEFT JOIN `mageplaza_brand` AS `br` ON main_table.option_id = br.option_id
                AND br.store_id = (SELECT MAX(ab.store_id) FROM `mageplaza_brand` AS `ab` WHERE (ab.option_id = br.option_id AND ab.store_id IN (0, 1)))
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_swatch` AS `sw` ON main_table.option_id = sw.option_id WHERE (`main_table`.`attribute_id` = '83') AND (tdv.store_id = 0) AND (IF(tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.value, tdv.value) REGEXP BINARY '^A') GROUP BY `main_table`.`option_id` ORDER BY `tdv`.`value` ASC, main_table.sort_order ASC, value ASC

Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3995 Character set 'utf8_general_ci' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like.

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3995 Character set 'utf8_general_ci' cannot be used in conjunction with 'binary' in call to regexp_like., query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `tdv`.`value` AS `default_value`, `tsv`.`value` AS `store_default_value`, IF(tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.value, tdv.value) AS `value`, IF(br.store_id = 1, br.brand_id, NULL) AS `brand_id`, `br`.`brand_id`, 1 AS `store_id`, `br`.`page_title`, `br`.`url_key`, `br`.`short_description`, `br`.`description`, `br`.`is_featured`, `br`.`static_block`, `br`.`meta_title`, `br`.`meta_keywords`, `br`.`meta_description`, `br`.`image`, `sw`.`type` AS `swatch_type`, `sw`.`value` AS `swatch_value` FROM `eav_attribute_option` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `tdv` ON tdv.option_id = main_table.option_id
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `tsv` ON tsv.option_id = main_table.option_id AND tsv.store_id = '1'
 LEFT JOIN `mageplaza_brand` AS `br` ON main_table.option_id = br.option_id
                AND br.store_id = (SELECT MAX(ab.store_id) FROM `mageplaza_brand` AS `ab` WHERE (ab.option_id = br.option_id AND ab.store_id IN (0, 1)))
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_swatch` AS `sw` ON main_table.option_id = sw.option_id WHERE (`main_table`.`attribute_id` = '83') AND (tdv.store_id = 0) AND (IF(tsv.value_id > 0, tsv.value, tdv.value) REGEXP BINARY '^A') GROUP BY `main_table`.`option_id` ORDER BY `tdv`.`value` ASC, main_table.sort_order ASC, value ASC

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute() called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php:303]
#2 Zend_Db_Statement->execute() called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php:480]
```

Comment: this is the error

link to website https://www.adorobeleza.com.br/marcas.html